# How to get client's system "Region and Language" settings on server?

Tags: javascript, http, date, format, globalization

Is there any way to get format settings (country from "Formats" tab on "Region and Language" popup in Windows) in JavaScript so I can pass it to server in cookie? (big target - display dates in correct format on MVC 4 server-side)

In IE9 I can use **navigator.UserLanguage** (also correct language is passed in **Accept-Language** http header).

But in Chrome and FF **navigator.UserLanguage** is undefined, **navigator.language** and **Accept-Language** returns browser's interface language.

Comment: You need to ask the user

Comment: Making an option in "Settings" section of the site is possible, but I am looking for transparent (for user) solution.

Comment: There is no way to get this setting. The only thing you can get is the browser language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for JS or anything else to access this setting, however there is the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE language property which can be accessed on the server. For example with PHP you can do:

```
 echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
```

which will echo something like `en-US`. In most cases this will probably be the users prefered language, so why not use it?

Comment: **HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE** is based on **Accept-Language** HTTP header, which reflects browser settings (not system ones). Only exception is IE whose settings are synchronised with global system ones. 
But yes, if no alternative exists this solution will be used.

Comment: I know, but usually the system language settings are the same as the browser language settings so for usual things you can rely on this information