# Browser Language undefined for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, browser, android-browser, mobile-browser

I am capturing browser language in my web page. The code is very simple as follows:

```
function browserLanguage() {

        return navigator.languages ? navigator.languages[0] : navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    }
```

At the server side I am capturing user agent from headers. But for this user agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-T713 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.124 Safari/537.36" , I am getting the language as undefined.

I googled and found out that the device is Samsung Tab and the browser used was Chrome. Does anyone any idea or the stable way to get the browser language.

PS: I can use only Javascript and no frameworks.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client's system "Region and Language" settings on server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281860/how-to-get-clients-system-region-and-language-settings-on-server)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  I use the exact same detection javascript and today got the same error.  Very similar useragent
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-A500FU Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.132 Mobile Safari/537.36